# Comet-Style API Consumption with Async/Await

Tags: c#, async-await, comet

I'm trying to read from a Comet style HTTP API which you connect to and it continuously pushes events. I want this to run in the background after it's started, but my Async/Await is erroneous it's freezing my UI and I don't know why.

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run((Func<Task>)PushEventReader);
}

public async Task PushEventReader()
{
    var uri = "url.to/api";
    var client = new WebClient();

    client.OpenReadCompleted += async (sender, e) =>
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(e.Result))
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
    };
    await client.OpenReadTaskAsync(new Uri(uri));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your button click event does not anything other than start a job in the background then there's no point in making asynchronous with `async` and there's no point in awaiting the `Task.Run` since you are not doing anything after that. You can simply have your button click like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Run(async () => await PushEventReader());
}
```

`Task.Run` will queue whatever work you pass to it to run on the ThreadPool which will effectively make it run on the background.

**Extra:** the `WebClient` you are using is an un-managed resource (you can notice that since it implements the `IDisposable` interface) and it is a good practice to use them inside a `using` block which will handle the disposing for you:

```
public async Task PushEventReader()
{
    var uri = "url.to/api";

    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.OpenReadCompleted += async (sender, e) =>
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(e.Result))
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var line = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
        };

        await client.OpenReadTaskAsync(new Uri(uri));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is `Task.Run` needed?

Comment: Is not needed, you can do it without the `Task.Run` and it should work in the same way, I believe they get compiled into the exact same IL code. But I prefer using `Task.Run` since it improves code readability in my opinion.